# How do I fire off a react action when url changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

So I'm building a website that users can view each others profiles. I have one Profile component and I want to show profiles based on users id. I'm sending those user id's as a url paramater.

My problem is if I switch from another users profile to my profile my `getProfileById` doesn't fire off (I have a my profile button that directly sends authenticated user's id to url paramater). I want to fire my action off when url change how do I do that?

Here is my `getProfileById` action code:

```js
export const getAllProfileById = (userId) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "CLEAR_PROFILE" });
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/api/profile/${userId}`);

        dispatch({
            type: "GET_PROFILE",
            payload: res.data.data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: "PROFILE_ERROR",
            payload: { msg: error.response.statusText, status: error.response.status }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is how I call `getProfileById` in my Profile component

```js
 useEffect(() => {

        if (!profile) {
            dispatch(getAllProfileById(id));
        }
    }, [dispatch])
```

Comment: Have you tried `useLocation` ? https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom`?

Comment: can you show us the route of the component which takes url parameter ? (example ```<Route path="/tweet/:id" exact component={TweetDetail} />```)

Comment: I tried to put location in useEffect but doesn't work

Comment: yes, im using react-router-dom

Comment: `<PrivateRoute exact path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />`

Comment: can you do a ```console.log(props.match.params.id)``` in the useEffect ?

Comment: console.log gives the right id everytime it changes. Like this 
`Profile.js:34 6091714f33b06727189ca942
Profile.js:34 6091714f33b06727189ca942
Profile.js:34 6091714f33b06727189ca942
Profile.js:34 609170f433b06727189ca93f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment section - you are using `react-router-dom` - you can use [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hooks to capture the changes with `useEffect` combination, see from the documentation:

> `useParams` returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters. Use it to access `match.params` of the current `<Route>`.

See a possible simplified working idea:

```
const Profile = () => {
  const { id } = useParams() // destructure the id param from the URL

  useEffect(() => {
     // here you can see a logging step once id is changing
     // based on the given dependency array
     console.log(id)

     // also you can dispatch your action as
     dispatch(getAllProfileById(id))
  }, [id])

  return <> your component's code </>
}
```

Of course if you have have different parameter name in the URL, just change it from `id` to the proper one.

Comment: Awesome, happy to help!